# Regular expression stop capturing after whitespace c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to not capture the body of the string. I ended up with this regular expression but it is still capturing whatever comes right after `Subject`. I need to capture datas from `From`, `To`, `Cc` and `Subject` only not including the body message. The problem lies with this regex pattern `Subject:\s*([\s\S]*)`, how do I modify this? I am still a newbie to regex.

This is my regex pattern : `@"From:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*To:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*Cc:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*Subject:\s*([\s\S]*)"`.

```
From:                                             trial@123.com 

To:                                               trial@123.com 

Cc:                                               trial@123.com

Subject:                                    Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum


 Lorem Ipsum,  


 Lorem Ipsum  


 Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum
```

Comment: Do you have any separator to identifiy subject and body? Without such an separator it's very hard to destinguish what is what. Maybe `\r?\n` is a valid separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your regex work the way you want you need to make the next:

- Enable [`Multiline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Multiline) option for `Regex` object in your code.
- Change this part of the regex `Subject:\s*([\s\S]*)` to the next `Subject:\s*([\s\S]*?)$`.

Here is working sample:

```
string text = @"From:                                             trial@123.com 

To:                                               trial@123.com 

Cc:                                               trial@123.com

Subject:                                    Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum 
Lorem Ipsum


 Lorem Ipsum,  


 Lorem Ipsum  


 Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum";

var regex = new Regex(
    @"From:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*To:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*Cc:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*Subject:\s*([\s\S]*?)$",
    RegexOptions.Multiline);

Match m in regex.Match(text));

// The first Group matches whole regex value. We skip it to show only
// matched From, To, Cc and Subject values.
foreach (Group g in m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Value);
}
```

---

***Explanation:***

- By enabling `Multiline` option we are able to use symbol `$` to match end of the line.
- `Subject:\s*([\s\S]*?)$`:

  - `$` at the end of this pattern says that it must match symbols till the end of the line.
  - We added `?` to make regex pattern for `Subject` not greedy. It means that `Subject` pattern will match till the first symbol `$` (end of line). If you remove `?` you make `Subject` regex pattern greedy and it will match till the last symbol `$`.

[Here](https://regexr.com/545ro) you can test this regex.

---

@kebbg asked in the comment:

> one question, lets say I don't want to just write it in a console and
>   I want to return the values from each match. Is that possible? Like
>   ,return (email of from:. ) , return email of to ...etc.

You can create a method that will find `From`, `To`, `Cc` and `Subject` values and return them from the method. Then you can use this method in your project:

```
public static EmailInfo GetEmailInfo(string emailBody)
{
    var regex = new Regex(
        @"From:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*To:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*Cc:\s*(\S*@\S*\.\S*)\s*Subject:\s*([\s\S]*?)$",
        RegexOptions.Multiline);

    Match m = regex.Match(emailBody);

    if (!m.Success)
       return null;

    return new EmailInfo
    {
        From = m.Groups[1].Value,
        To = m.Groups[2].Value,
        Cc = m.Groups[3].Value,
        Subject = m.Groups[4].Value,
    };
}

public class EmailInfo
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Cc { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: one question, lets say I don't want to just write it in a console and I want to return the values from each match. Is that possible? Like ,return (email of from:. ) ,  return email of to ...etc.

Comment: @kebbg I updated my answer and included information how to return matched values as an object.